# et al appears in first citation

Tags: citing, natbib, bst

I recently started using Latex and need some help.

Sorry as I'm new to Latex I don't exactly know how everything works.
All critique and response of the structure of this post is welcome.

When citing more than three authors I want et al. to appear but not the first time it's cited.
However now et al. appears every time.

I created a custom bst file with `makebst` and and using `\citet*` or `longnamesfirst` have no effect.

When making the costum bibstyle I chose Natbib for author year support system.

Here is the parts from the dbj think is relevant

```
%<<AUTHORS IN CITATIONS:
%   %: (def) One author et al for three or more authors
  mcite,%: Some other truncation scheme 
%------\ans=m(==mcite)-------
%>>AUTHORS IN CITATIONS:
%<<MAX AUTHORS BEFORE ET AL: (if regular cite not selected)
  mct-1,%: One et al 
% mct-2,%: One, Two et al 
% mct-3,%: One, Two, Three et al 
% mct-4,%: One, Two, Three, Four et al 
% mct-5,%: One, Two, Three, Four, Five et al 
% mct-6,%: One, Two, Three, Four, Five, Six et al 
%------\ans=*(==mct-1)-------
%>>MAX AUTHORS BEFORE ET AL: (if regular cite not selected)
%<<MAX AUTHORS WITHOUT ET AL: (if regular cite not selected)
% mct-x2,%: Two authors without truncating 
  mct-x3,%: Three authors without truncating
% mct-x4,%: Four authors without truncating
% mct-x5,%: Five authors without truncating
% mct-x6,%: Six authors without truncating
%------\ans=3(==mct-x3)-------
%>>MAX AUTHORS WITHOUT ET AL: (if regular cite not selected)
%<<TYPEFACE FOR AUTHORS IN LIST OF REFERENCES:
    %: (def) Normal font for author names 
% nmft,nmft-sc,%: Small caps authors (\sc)
% nmft,nmft-it,%: Italic authors (\it or \em)
% nmft,nmft-bf,%: Bold authors (\bf)
% nmft,nmft-def,%: User defined author font (\bibnamefont)
%------\ans=*(==)-------
```

Here is what I think is relevant in my preamble.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage[longnamesfirst]{natbib}
```

Here how i invoked it in text

```
 \citet*{akerlof1996macroeconomics} \citet{akerlof1996macroeconomics}
```

It looks like this in the output

[image]

Do I have to change anything in my bst file or is there another simple solution to this?

I would be truly grateful for any help

Comment: You load both `\usepackage{graphics}` and `\usepackage{graphicx}`; you should only use the latter, the former is obselete. For the actual question, please post a minimal working example. You so far only posted the preamble: This is both too much (the majority of the packages in there have nothing to do with the problem) and too little (we do not see your `\documentclass{}` and how you invoke citations in text). Please limit the example to a minimal, compilable example that shows the error. As you use a custom bibstyle, we potentially need that as well and/or how you created it (`makebst`?).

Comment: @ManuelWeinkauf Thank you so much for all the feedback and help! I think I have corrected my post after your suggestion. Let me know if any more info is needed.